# How to create DAX measure if statement across Power BI tables?

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dataset, dax, calculation

I have a Power BI dataset with the following tables, all tables after Invoice details have a one to many relationship with the invoice table.

**Tables:**
Invoice details,
customer,
date,
product, and
sales company.

In my visualization I have a table with the set up pictured below:

[image]

There are multiple product IDs for each invoice number.

How can I create a DAX measure that says, if the Sales Org ID is "IDH", divide price by 0.5, all else to be divided by 0.7?

My current formula is this:

```
_Calculated Units = 
if(SELECTEDVALUE('Sales Company'[Sales Org ID]) = "IDH", sum('INVOICE DETAILS'[Price]) / 0.5, sum('INVOICE DETAILS'[Price]) / 0.7)
```

But this results in an error when I add it to the visualization. I don't want to create a calculated column, any ideas on how to create this measure?

Comment: You may want to share the error message from the visual as well.

Comment: Are you creating some kind of aggregation (SUM, MIN, MAX)? Normally, you do what you're describing by using an iterator (SUMX, MINX, MAXX), because iterator functions can "see" the related records in other tables.

Also, no star schema? why not?

Comment: I figured it out. if(SELECTEDVALUE('Sales Company'[Sales Org ID]) = "IDH", sum('INVOICE DETAILS'[Price]) / 0.5, if(SELECTEDVALUE('Sales Company'[Sales Org ID]) = "GAD",sum('INVOICE DETAILS'[Price]) / 0.7))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Switched to a dataset with less data and didn't receive an error.

```
if(SELECTEDVALUE('Sales Company'[Sales Org ID]) = "IDH", sum('INVOICE DETAILS'[Price]) / 0.5, if(SELECTEDVALUE('Sales Company'[Sales Org ID]) = "GAD",sum('INVOICE DETAILS'[Price]) / 0.7))
```